# How do I tell if I'm leaking COM objects?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I'm writing some code that makes (relatively simple) use of COM, calling AddRef() on some objects and Release()ing them later. Other than just checking the code really thoroughly, is there a way I can check to see if I'm leaking COM objects everywhere?

(I can't use reference counted `IBlahBlahPtr`s because I need to pass the objects to a set of APIs who don't know what a COM is, and so don't understand the whole "reference counting pointers" thingy - they pass the pointer around like a token.)

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the APIs you are passing COM pointers to don't know that they're COM pointers, and thus don't call IUnknown functions.  If so, couldn't you still use `IBlahBlahPtr` objects in your own code and just pass pointer values to the APIs (and instantiate new `IBlahBlahPtr` objects around pointers that you get back from those APIs)?

Comment: We're trying to expose the functionality of a COM API (MSXML in this case) in a few simple functions. So for example, our "create XML document" function needs to return what is actually an `IXMLDOMDocument *`, but as far as the caller knows, it's just a token that identifies the document in an implementation defined way. The same API will be reimplemented on OS X, where COM isn't even a thing, and it'll return a similar platform-specific token.

Answer (score 1):

It is no different from checking for leaks in any C or C++ code.  Use `<crtdbg.h>` to detect leaks, the MSDN library article [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  You'll get a leak report for the class factory if there were not enough IUnknown::Release() calls.

Reference counting interface pointers is a hard COM requirement, you cannot just shrug it off.  If the client code doesn't do it then you'll have to take care of it yourself before you pass a pointer to that code.  Knowing when the pointer is no longer in use is of course the trickier issue.

Comment: It sounds as if the questioner is not implementing a COM server, but rather just using COM objects.  So heap checking won't do the trick.  Also, it doesn't sound like the questioner is "shrugging off" the responsibility for COM pointer management ("Other than just checking the code really thoroughly...").

Comment: Yes, could be.  The show is kinda over if the server isn't debuggable. Yes, checking really thoroughly.  And unit tests of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CrtDebug DEBUG_NEW to allocate your objects, you'll get an automatic dump of all leaked objects at exit time (basically, all memory that is not freed), along with the file name and line where the memory was allocated.

Comment: The same comment I made to Hans Passant applies to DEBUG_NEW; if the questioner's heap isn't the one in which the COM objects are actually being allocated, then this technique won't help.

Comment: He would have to build the com library using DEBUG_NEW, of course.  Looking at the comments to the original question, I see that he's trying to use MSXML -- so it's doubtful he could build its own version of these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation in comments, I'd say you could do the following:

- Use smart pointers (i.e., `IBlahBlahPtr`) to create and manage COM objects in your own code.
- Maintain a collection of smart pointers representing your caller's references to the pointers that you've passed upwards.  Every time you hand a new COM pointer over to your caller, put its smart pointer in the collection.
- If your caller relinquishes a COM pointer somehow (by, say, passing you the COM pointer token in some kind of "release" function), then look up its smart pointer in the collection and remove it.  If that smart pointer (representing the caller's now-defunct reference to the object) is the only remaining holder of a reference count on the object, then destruction will occur as desired.
- If your caller passes you a COM pointer in a non-relinquishing way, you can wrap a new smart pointer object around the raw pointer value for the duration of the call, just so that your use of smart pointers within your own code is consistent.  It's fine for multiple smart pointers to refer to the same COM object.

Answer (score 0):

Various tools will check for you.  BoundsChecker does.  I think, but am not 100% sure, that AppVerifier does (it has the added benefit of being free).